# Синтаксис UNIX-комманд в Objective-C

Tags: macos, unix, objective-c

Всем привет!

Очень нубские вопросы по Mac OS X программированию.
Хочу сделать очень простой образец приложения для Mac OS X .
Задачи:

1.При включении приложение посылает команду на терминал. Раньше ничего не делал под десктоп, но я так понимаю что в моем случае я иду в AppDelegate.m и пишу:

```
<code>-(void)awakeFromNib: {
      //код для вызова unix-команды 
}</code>
```

Интересует синтаксис такого кода, и в этом методе его делать или в -`applicationDidFinishLaunching:`  ?

2.После выполнения этой команды апп должен сразу же закрыться. В этом же методе прописать -`applicationWillTerminate`?

Заранее большое спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system("ваша команда системе");`, оно из си и прекрасно сработает в обж-с

Comment: system работает как и планировалось, большое спасибо!  А как послать приложению терминэйт?

Comment: Если знаете его PID, то системным вызовом kill()  (см. man 2 kill)

Comment: Вероятно я не точно выразился. Требуется чтобы приложение само себя закрывало. По видимому конструкция типа 

[self applicationWillTerminate];

но я не знаю что именно, сейчас роюсь в terminate-методах

Comment: Просто exit(0) не подойдет?

Comment: @AlexThumb, вызовите `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate: nil];` в том месте, где нужно завершить работу приложения.

Comment: Большое спасибо, коллеги! Ваши советы очень помогли!